# iOS 15.7 keeps resetting screen time 'always available' apps

Tags: ios, screen-time

For about a week or so now, screentime on my iphone is totally messed up.
All of the apps which were flagged under 'always available' have been removed.

I have tried the suggestion of 'switch off screentime and restart your iphone' which does not work. Any apps I re-add are soon removed somehow.

This occured on iOS 15.6 and now even on 15.7

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Also experiencing this. I just updated the Always Allowed a month ago, and it just reset on me.

Comment: Now MacOS is contaminated with this too. I am running the latest version of MacOS.